# Define on-topic and off-topic reasons in the help center

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope

One of the reasons on which many users are confused is **on-topic and off-topic**. If you once look at our meta home page, you will see that many questions are like *Are questions about X on-topic here?*

> *[Are essential oil topic questions on-topic here?](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/are-essential-oil-questions-on-topic)*
>     *[Are recipes related questions on topic or should they be moved to cooking.stackexchange?](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/are-recipes-related-questions-on-topic-or-should-they-be-moved-to-cooking-stacke/14#14)*
>   *[Are sorta-vegetarian diets on topic?](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-sorta-vegetarian-diets-on-topic)*
>   *[Is nutrition on-topic?](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/is-nutrition-on-topic)*

These are the questions I found and on the main site, we are seeing some questions. For example:

> 1. [How to remove pesticides and harmful bacteria from fruits and vegetables?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/169/how-to-remove-pesticides-and-harmful-bacteria-from-fruits-and-vegetables)
> 2. [Are mango seeds edible?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/201/are-mango-seeds-edible)
> 3. [Is boiling orange or lemon peels and drinking it as a tea healthy?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/216/is-boiling-orange-or-lemon-peels-and-drinking-it-as-a-tea-healthy)

From the above list,

- Question 1 is closed.
- Question 2 is closed but has a reopen vote.
- Question 3 is closed as off-topic.

To me question 2 and question 3 are off-topic. They fit in Health.SE. But one of our friends answered of the above questions and said this:

> Being on topic somewhere else doesn't make them off-topic here.

To remove confusion about on-topic and off-topic, can we add the off-topic reasons in [help center](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? Currently there is nothing defined as off-topic. Same applies for [on-topic](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

If we consider our personal opinions as on-topic and off-topic, it greatly affects the site quality. Adding these reasons would decrease duplicate questions and off-topic questions, and it would also reduce the number of disputed flags and burden on experienced users and moderators.

For example: The [on-topic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page of [Hinduism.SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/).

*Keep your answers short and simple and add reasons why they are off-topic. Please one reason per answer*.

Comment: I agree that the help center should give such guidance, once a reasonable degree of community consensus has been arrived at through discussion here on meta :)

Comment: Related, my question about whether we consider "Is X veg*n?" off topic. The consensus seems to be that [it is](http://meta.vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/28/should-we-allow-questions-on-defining-what-is-isnt-vegetarian).

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan to clarify, you mean "The consensus seems to be that it is off-topic", correct?

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Sorry, yes I meant to say consensus indicates that it is off topic.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Gives your views in the answer field so that mods can add [tag:status-completed] or [status-declined] later.

Comment: Also, now with mods: we can edit this.  What would you like to add? 1 big answer would be nice.

Comment: @Riker One big answer isn't cool. One person can't add all the on-topic and off-topic reasons. COmmunity should add them.

Comment: @SS. only mods can edit the on-topic reasons. I meant a community wiki answer, where anybody can instantly edit it.

Comment: @Riker Yes. I know mods can add. As you wish. Anything which would help the site get a basic structure on which is on-topic is fine.

Answer (score 3):

I asked

[Are questions asking for local or travel advice on-topic?](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/are-questions-asking-for-local-or-travel-advice-on-topic)

and it seems the answer is no.

But this should be interpreted sensitively I think: only close as off-topic if the answers are likely to be highly opinion based and go out of date quickly. A question with broader scope like "Vegetarian foods in Japanese culture" should be considered on-topic in my opinion, as answers are likely to help many people and remain useful over time

Answer (score -2):

I've already asked about whether or not we should allow "Is X veg*n?" and the consensus is that these questions are off topic.

> [Should we allow questions on defining what is/isn't vegetarian?](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/should-we-allow-questions-on-defining-what-is-isnt-vegetarian)

I'd suggest a close reason along the lines of

> Asking whether something is vegan/vegetarian is off topic as it's mostly down to personal opinion. They're broad lifestyles without anyone to lay out strict guidelines, so there wont be any definitive answers.

Comment: I'm on-board with that being in the help certain, but I don't know if we should make it a close reason. We only get 3 custom ones, and we may come up with others.

Comment: we seem to have lots of questions asking whether x y or z is vegan so I'm downvoting this suggestion as nobody seems to object to those questions and they are for the most part pretty answerable with qualifications