# What kinds of shopping questions are OK?

Tags: discussion, scope

Here's some example questions...

- [How can I Electric Power, Water Wash soiled fruits and vegetables?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2474/how-can-i-electric-power-water-wash-soiled-fruits-and-vegetables)
- [Is there a vegan or vegetarian instant noodles?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2345/is-there-a-vegan-or-vegetarian-instant-noodles)
- [What is a healthy seasoning powder for vegetarians?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/what-is-a-healthy-seasoning-powder-for-vegetarians)

There may be others but they are characterised by asking for where to buy something. Of course one problem with that is that it's often country specific and may change over time as different manufacturers change their product lines.

Many sites disallow such questions, we currently don't - at least we moderators aren't closing these questions. Do you want us to close them? Or are some kinds of shopping questions OK and others not?

Sites that disallow shopping questions [do so because](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-was-my-shopping-list-question-closed) they tend to be open-ended, become obsolete quickly, and attract low quality answers and/or spam. I'm not convinced we have that problem, at least not in any quantity that we can't moderate and therefore perhaps we're OK to allow them.

Related previous discussion on V&V: [Are questions asking for local or travel advice on-topic?](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/are-questions-asking-for-local-or-travel-advice-on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Finding products to support a veg*n lifestyle is so important, especially to those just starting out and looking to replace their everyday foods. I think shopping questions need to be on topic here, even though they require more moderation work than other types of questions.

I think we should try to guide people to make their shopping questions detailed and specific. For example, they could say what country or region or type of settlement they are living in, or specify how they use some product they are looking to replace.